# Parsing issue in Swift 3.0

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am using the Swift 3.0 and Almofire. In below data how I can use `url` key's value from this response data.

Printing description of `parsedData`:

```
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "status_txt"
    - .1 : OK
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "status_code"
    - .1 : 200
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "data"
    ▿ .1 : 5 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - .0 : long_url
        - .1 : http://google.com
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - .0 : hash
        - .1 : 2lOLF92
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - .0 : global_hash
        - .1 : 2lOL6fc
      ▿ 3 : 2 elements
        - .0 : url
        - .1 : http://google.com
      ▿ 4 : 2 elements
        - .0 : new_hash
        - .1 : 1

Alamofire.request("http://my url").responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
    switch responseObject.result {
    case .success(let data):
        let bytes = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        var jsonObj = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: bytes, options: .mutableLeaves)
        print("parsedData\(jsonObj)")

    case .failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: data is using to parse errors from server. You should use response.result to get your objects. and also use [weak self] in your clojures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used [`Response JSON Handler`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-json-handler) not the [`Response Data Handler`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-data-handler), so in this case with `case .success(let data)` you will get Serialized `JSON` response so need to use again `JSONSerialization` with it, Simply convert it to array and you can go for it.

```
Alamofire.request("http://my url").responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
    switch responseObject.result {
    case .success(let value): //batter to use value
        if let dictionary = value as? [String:Any], 
           let dataDic = dictionary["data"] as? [String:Any],
           let url = dataDic["url"] as? String {
               print(url)
        }


    case .failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I did as you said but It is not validating the if condition so I am not able to print the nested array.

Comment: Yo print nested array, you should create sub model, root model will continue  the whole array, sub model will continute nested objects. So you can print it with do e.q. rootArray.mainObject.object

Comment: print(responseObject.result.value)

Optional({
    data =     {
        "global_hash" = 2lJlC78;
        hash = 2lJyNF0;
        "long_url" = http://google.com;
        "new_hash" = 1;
        url = http://google.com;
    };
    "status_code" = 200;
    "status_txt" = OK;
})

Comment: @RahulGupta Welcome mate :)